# Не видно кастомные поля при экспорте в WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня есть сайт на WordPress WooCommerce. Я использую плагин WP Ultimate CSV Importer - Custom Fields Import для того чтобы импортировать товары из CSV файла к себе на сайт.

Ранее в function.php я добавил новые кастомные поля, которые выводятся на странице товара:

```
// Add Custom Pricing Field to Product Data Meta Box
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'wbac_add_custom_field', 5);
function wbac_add_custom_field()
{
    global $post;
    woocommerce_wp_text_input([
        'id'        => 'wbac_customer_pricing',
        'label'     => 'Цена для клиента',
        'value'     => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wbac_customer_pricing', true),
        'data_type' => 'price',
    ]);
}
// Save Custom Pricing Field
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'wbac_save_custom_field');
function wbac_save_custom_field($post_id)
{
    $customer_pricing = $_POST['wbac_customer_pricing'];
    // END НДС
    if (!empty($customer_pricing)) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'wbac_customer_pricing', wc_format_decimal($customer_pricing));
    }
}
```

В настройках плагина есть такой пункт CMB2 Meta Fields prefix, в нём я указал "wbac". Но при импортировании я вижу только стандартные поля WordPress WooCommerce. Что я делаю не так?

Тоже самое пробовал делать и с WP All Import, всё аналогично, кастомные поля не видно. Мучаюсь уже месяц.. буду благодарен за любую подсказку

Comment: WP All Import нормально импортирует кастомные поля. Но только в платной версии https://i.imgur.com/m5eJttu.jpeg

Comment: Нет, тоже не видит среди кастомных полей, пробовал платную версию WP All Import

Comment: Значит что-то не так делал.